# css margin left and right issues

Tags: html, css

i want to get the bit at the top of some websites that really thin and right at the top. which looks like facebooks blue banner at the top of their website.

the code i have tried for the above is:

```
<div style="height:20px; background-color:grey; margin-top:-10px; "></div>
```

and it works apart from theres just a little bit of white space at the right and left sides of the grey.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Show your html markup as well and it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't cleared the padding/margin on the `body` element. Give this a go:

```
html, body
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also, give your div a width of `100%`:

```
div
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've probably gone a bit overboard with the CSS, but it will make sure everything works.

Additionally, make sure there is an HTML [doctype](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp) defined - this can cause some other problems later one, such as `:hover` not working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `margin:0` on the `html` and `body` tags. This will allow your div to take up all the available horizontal space, and put it right at the top instead of having a small space.